# How can I add GoogleAdsense to React Native Web (not mobile)?

Tags: react-native, adsense, google-ads-script

I wrote web app with react native and I want to add google adsense. All I can find is 'React', not 'React Native'. I followed that and got Error 400 (Bad Request). Even 'React Native', it was all about mobile app, not web app. Can someone show me how to add Ads to React Native Web App?

```
export const InArticleAds = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    (window.adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
  }, []);

  return (
    <ins
      className="adsbygoogle"
      style={{ display: "block", textAlign: "center" }}
      data-ad-layout="in-article"
      data-ad-format="fluid"
      data-ad-client="ca-pub-9172738714424609"
      data-ad-slot="6235565279"
    ></ins>
  );
};
```

That is what I tried.